# How to freeze a column using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a two column layout via CSS, and I'm wondering how I can make the list on the sidebar column stay frozen down as the user scrolls down on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS property:

```
 position: fixed;
```

The description of it might be "The element is positioned relative to the browser window", I assume this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! Now I just have to figure out how to make it not overlap with my top nav.

Comment: consider adding z-index. add to your nav position: relative; z-index: 10; and to your side column z-index: 1